# Iterate single graphs using ggplot 2

Tags: sql, r, ggplot2

Please look to the code below (some proprietary info let out, but intention should come across):

```
query <- "Select  convert(varchar(10),PRICE_DATE,103) as Price_date, ISIN, PRICE_SRC, PRICE from ``
    where ISIN in ('BE0119096775',
    'US80685QAA40',
    'US00139PAA66',
    'US705010AB25')
     and PRICE_DATE > '20140101' and PRICE_SRC in ('BRC_INDEX', 'REUTERS','BVAL')
    order by ISIN, PRICE_DATE"

# Squish query to a flat string
query <- strwrap(query,width=nchar(query),simplify=TRUE)

# Open database, grab data and close connection
ch <- odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=;Database=;", rows_at_time = 1024)
result <- sqlQuery(ch, query, as.is=c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE))
close(ch)

result <- (na.omit(result))

names(result)[1] <- "Price_Date"

result$Price_Date <- as.Date(result$Price_Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
result$PRICE_SRC <- as.character(result$PRICE_SRC) 
result$PRICE <- as.numeric(result$PRICE)
result$PRICE_SRC <- as.factor(result$PRICE_SRC)

result$PRICE_SRC <- factor(result$PRICE_SRC, levels=c("BRC_INDEX","BVAL","REUTERS"),labels=c("Vendor1","Vendor2","REUTERS"))

result <- melt(result, id=c("Price_Date","PRICE_SRC","PRICE"))

ggplot(data=result, aes(x=Price_Date, y=PRICE, group = PRICE_SRC, colour = PRICE_SRC)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point( size=4, shape=21, fill="white") +
  facet_wrap(~value, ncol = 2)
```

I have used `facet_wrap` to make charts of each `ISIN` in the data frame = result. Prefferably I would like to make "single" graphs without having to write the code "over and over" again. So the question is if anybody could help out on the ggplot syntax of anyother for that matter to create multiple graphs from one data frame as done above.

The results will be a series of observation for each `ISIN` splitted by vendor and dates.

Thanks and sorry for any obvious mistakes in my question .

Lh

Answer (score 2):

what about `filter()` from the `dplyr` package.

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)
```

#### example data:

```
data <- data.frame( var = rep(letters[1:3],each=10), value = rnorm(30) )
```

#### filter and plot:

You can filter your main data frame for a particular variable like so:

```
tmp_data <- filter(data,var == "a")
plot_object <-  ggplot(tmp_data,aes(value)) + geom_density()
```

You can do the same thing by using the `magrittr` piping syntax:

```
plot_object <- data %>% 
                    filter(var == "a") %>% 
                    ggplot(., aes(value)) + geom_density()
```

#### iterating through all the variables:

To iterate through all of the variables and plot them one-at-a-time you can do something like:

```
 plot_object_ls <- lapply( levels(data$var),
                                function(x) {
                                        data %>% 
                                        filter(var == x) %>% 
                                        ggplot(., aes(value)) + geom_density()
                                            })
```

Then `plot_object_ls` at the console will plot them all if this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the example and tutorial!

Comment: Tried this:
result$value <- as.factor(result$value)



plot_result_it <- lapply( levels(result$value),
                          function(x) {
                            data %>% 
                              filter(var == x) %>% 
                              ggplot(., aes(value)) + geom_line()
                          })

But ended up with a comment: Error in exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode) : 
  argument "env" is missing, with no default

Any further instruction ? 

Thank you very much :))

Comment: @user2262528 read your code: it's telling you `error in exists` or in other words `something doesn't exist!`. as you've written it you are filtering for `var == levels(result$value)` which will be nothing and you pass this to ggplot which causes the error. __compare your code to the last section of my answer__ and you will find the difference. Also, just for future notice: if you format your comments with `code` and _other formatting_ it will be easier to read through!

Comment: Sorry for my lack of understanding on this topic, but trying to learn. When i pass it value ( factor variable with 3 levels) I want it to iterate through those three without passing any further arguments.

Comment: @user2262528 this is precisely what is done with the `lapply` call in my answer: "for each of the levels of the factor `var` in data.frame `data` individually filter `data` and plot density of `value`. to plot `geom_line()` or `geom_point()` you need to specify the columns that correspond to both x and y in the `aes(x=, y=)`.

Comment: Ended up doing this

`doPlot = function(isin) {
  #temp_df <- subset(result, value == result$value)
  # Lage ggplot 
  ggobj = ggplot(subset(result, value == isin), aes(x=Price_Date, y=PRICE, group = PRICE_SRC, colour = PRICE_SRC)) + geom_line()
  
  # justeringer
  ggobj = ggobj + ggtitle(isin) + xlab("Price Date") + 
    ylab("Price")
  
  # Need to use print() to actually produce the plot
  print(ggobj)
  
  # Save to PDF
  ggsave(sprintf("%s.pdf", isin))
}`